# Does using a software delay() function have greater power consumption than using a System Timer interrupt?

Tags: arm, interrupts, delay

I had a discussion with someone about using a software delay(), and how it just executes NOP commands for a specified number of clock cycles according to your delay, and thus is constantly running and consuming power. The alternative according to my reading is to use system timers. But, once these timers are enabled they also increment for the same number of clock periods so I would think the power consumption would be similar.

I wanted to know whether there is a difference in power usage between the two, keeping aside the fact that delay() blocks your program and stuff. Are there alternative delay methods that I'm unaware of as well that lead to better power consumption?

As there are too many variables to properly answer, I'll try and provide an example. The example task is to continuously display the number of seconds passed on a 7-segment LED display, wrapping back around to 0 once 60 seconds is reached. So I guess the goal would be to compare efficiency of a 1 second delay of using a function vs. SysTick IRQ

Comment: software delay does not execute only NOP. ... it may use NOP for very short delays. ... it probably watches the system timer in a loop

Comment: if the interrupt wakes the cpu from sleep, then that would save power .... if the interrupt redirects execution to an ISR while the cpu is busy doing something else, then that would not save power

Comment: This question is too broad, as it is unanswerable in the general case and no specific are given.  A delay function may be many different things, a system may be running other tasks, and it may or may not have frequency scaling or the ability to enter a low-power mode when not doing much.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I see your point. I was actually asked about this in an interview and the main point was the power consumption for using a blocking delay() function. I'll edited my post to give a specific example.

Comment: There are many meaningful discussions you could have following from such a question, and in so doing show a depth of knowledge of the subject matter.  But this is not a discussion site.  Consider the timer interrupt case; what will the program be doing until the interrupt fires?   Unless you can yield() to another useful thread, or dial back the processor power consumption, something like busy waiting for a flag set by the ISR to change is no cheaper than counting NOP's in the first place.  On multitasking systems also consider that `sleep(1)` is both blocking and potentially efficient.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Being curious myself I've made some simple measurements on a [32L152CDISCOVERY](http://www.st.com/en/evaluation-tools/32l152cdiscovery.html) board. My test program consists of 4 tests, each displaying the elapsed seconds on the LCD. The difference between the test is what they do until a second elapses.

- The first test does nothing inside the loop. It's a pure "busy loop", spinning until a variable changes.
- The second loop has a single `NOP` instruction inside.
- The third loop executes 1000 `NOP` instructions in a row.
- The fourth loop executes a `WFI` instruction, sleeping until an interrupt occurs.

Pressing the blue button advances to the next test.

There are two compile-time parameters.

- Defining `SLOWTICK` changes the `SysTick` interrupt frequency from 1 kHz to 1 Hz.
- Defining `ALIGN_OFF` inserts a `NOP` before each test loop, changing their alignment.

The code:

```
#define STM32L152xC
#include "stm32l1xx.h"
#include "lcd.h"

//#define SLOWTICK
//#define ALIGN_OFF

volatile int tick_s;
void SysTick_Handler() {
#ifdef SLOWTICK
    tick_s += 1;
#else
    static int tick_ms;
    tick_ms += 1;
    if(tick_ms == 1000) {
        tick_ms = 0;
        tick_s += 1;
    }
#endif
}

void hw_init() {
    // use the 16MHz internal HSI as clock source, no PLL
    RCC->CR |= RCC_CR_HSION;
    while(!(RCC->CR & RCC_CR_HSIRDY))
        ;
    RCC->CFGR |= RCC_CFGR_SW_HSI;
    while((RCC->CFGR & RCC_CFGR_SWS) != RCC_CFGR_SWS_HSI)
        ;
    SystemCoreClockUpdate();

    // enable GPIOs for the LCD and the pushbutton
    RCC->AHBENR = RCC_AHBENR_GPIOAEN | RCC_AHBENR_GPIOBEN | RCC_AHBENR_GPIOCEN;
    __ISB(); // wait a bit, see STM32L1 errata on RCC
    lcd_init();
#ifdef SLOWTICK
    SysTick_Config(SystemCoreClock);
#else
    SysTick_Config(SystemCoreClock / 1000);
#endif
}

int last_s = -1;

void display_s() {
    int d1 = (last_s / 10) % 10;
    int d2 = last_s % 10;
    lcd_displaychar(d1 + '0', 0, 0, 5);
    lcd_displaychar(d2 + '0', 0, 0, 6);
    lcd_update();
}

// repeats an instruction 10 times
#define TEN(x) ({ ({ x; }); ({ x; }); ({ x; }); ({ x; }); ({ x; }); \
                  ({ x; }); ({ x; }); ({ x; }); ({ x; }); ({ x; }); })

int button_pressed() {
    return GPIOA->IDR & 1;
}

int main() {
    hw_init();
    int temp_s;
    while(1) {
        lcd_displaytext("0NOP");
        asm volatile(".align 4");
#ifdef ALIGN_OFF
        asm volatile("nop");
#endif
        while(1) {
            while(1) {
                temp_s = tick_s;
                if(temp_s != last_s)
                    break;
            }
            last_s = temp_s;
            display_s();
            if(button_pressed())
                break;
        }
        while(button_pressed())
            ;

        lcd_displaytext("1NOP");
        asm volatile(".align 4");
#ifdef ALIGN_OFF
        asm volatile("nop");
#endif
        while(1) {
            while(1) {
                temp_s = tick_s;
                if(temp_s != last_s)
                    break;
                asm volatile("nop");
            }
            last_s = temp_s;
            display_s();
            if(button_pressed())
                break;
        }
        while(button_pressed())
            ;

        lcd_displaytext("xNOP");
        asm volatile(".align 4");
#ifdef ALIGN_OFF
        asm volatile("nop");
#endif
        while(1) {
            while(1) {
                temp_s = tick_s;
                if(temp_s != last_s)
                    break;
                // triple nesting repeats 10*10*10 times
                TEN(TEN(TEN(asm volatile("nop"))));
            }
            last_s = temp_s;
            display_s();
            if(button_pressed())
                break;
        }
        while(button_pressed())
            ;

        lcd_displaytext("WFI");
        asm volatile(".align 4");
#ifdef ALIGN_OFF
        asm volatile("nop");
#endif
        while(1) {
            while(1) {
                temp_s = tick_s;
                if(temp_s != last_s)
                    break;
                asm volatile("wfi");
            }
            last_s = temp_s;
            display_s();
            if(button_pressed())
                break;
        }
        while(button_pressed())
            ;
    }
}
```

Power consumption of the MCU was measured by connecting an ammeter between pins 1 and 2 of JP1. The debugger war disconnected by removing the jumper caps from CN3.

```
                      +--------+--------+--------+--------+
                      | Test 1 | Test 2 | Test 3 | Test 4 |
                      | 0NOP   | 1NOP   | xNOP   | WFI    |
+---------------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| //#define SLOWTICK  |        |        |        |        |
| //#define ALIGN_OFF | 4.3 mA | 4.7 mA | 2.8 mA | 1.4 mA |
+---------------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| //#define SLOWTICK  |        |        |        |        |
| #define ALIGN_OFF   | 5.0 mA | 4.8 mA | 2.8 mA | 1.4 mA |
+---------------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| #define SLOWTICK    |        |        |        |        |
| //#define ALIGN_OFF | 4.3 mA | 4.7 mA | 2.8 mA | 1.4 mA |
+---------------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| #define SLOWTICK    |        |        |        |        |
| #define ALIGN_OFF   | 4.9 mA | 4.8 mA | 2.8 mA | 1.4 mA |
+---------------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

Conclusions:

- Changing code alignment can significatly affect consumption.
- Executing lots of `NOP` instructions reduces consumption, but it can be tricky to generate the exact number of instructions needed for a particular delay. Not to mention the memory requirement.
- Putting the controller to sleep is the real power saver.

Answer (score 2):

So, a busy loop (like the `delay()` you're describing, probably not the `delay` you're actually using) will keep your CPU core running at full speed.

When you just idle the CPU core and wait for an interrupt, just a much, much simpler hardware counter runs. "Much simpler" means that clocking that switches much fewer transistors, and power usage in digital circuitry is usually the energy that's lost when switching a transistor.

For long times, you can really turn off the clock generator of the CPU core, and that saves even more power.

Answer (score 0):

This question is one that is going to be influenced by so many variables that it becomes essentially unanswerable. Here are some reasons why:

1. In the case of the NOP loops is the timer already running doing something else?
2. In the case of using the timer for the delay is the software polling waiting for the timer to expire?
3. When the timer is in use for the delay is the software execution put into a SLEEP mode?
4. Is the software keeping the loop counter for the NOP counter in a register or an memory location?
5. If a memory location is being used is the memory on chip or external in another component?
6. If external does the processor implement some type on external memory caching algorithm?

There are other considerations as well.

I would suspect that if you are using a modern MCU with onboard program memory and data memory that it will be hard to see much power difference for short delays. In this scenario there can be measurable power savings realized for long delays when the SLEEP mode of the MCU is used.

Comment: Thanks for all the points, I tried to provide a simple example in my edited post. Does that help narrow things down or is it still too general?